# Given a number, Generate a series of 'L' shaped matrix with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

Given any number. Lets say for example `5`, I need to generate a matrix similar to this:

```
 1     2     3     4     5
 2     2     3     4     5
 3     3     3     4     5
 4     4     4     4     5
 5     5     5     5     5
```

How to generate a matrix similar to this using Matlab?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html?refresh=true):

```
n = 5;
matrix = bsxfun(@max, 1:n, (1:n).');
```

An alternative (probably slower) is to use [`ndgrid`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html):

```
n = 5;
[ii, jj] = ndgrid(1:n);
matrix = max(ii, jj);
```

Comment: Best use of `bsxfun` here!

Comment: very nice :) i should have worked hard before posting this question .

Answer (score 2):

Nothing will ever beat [**`bsxfun` as used by Luis Mendo**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30027263/2605073)., but for the sake of reminding people of the existence of Matlab's [**`gallery`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gallery.html) function, here another approach:

```
n = 5;
A = gallery('minij',n)
B = n + 1 - A(end:-1:1,end:-1:1)
```

---

```
A =

     1     1     1     1     1
     1     2     2     2     2
     1     2     3     3     3
     1     2     3     4     4
     1     2     3     4     5


B =

     1     2     3     4     5
     2     2     3     4     5
     3     3     3     4     5
     4     4     4     4     5
     5     5     5     5     5
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know a new function. :)

Comment: Nice! The `gallery` function can generate many different matrices indeed